# Getting random too many CLOSE_WAIT states on heavy load on middleware server(Jetty 9.3.XX)

Tags: java, mysql, tcp, ubuntu-14.04, jetty-9

We have developed Jersey web application(REST APIs) and below are the details about used libraries/technologies:

- Jersey - v2.23.1 Open JPA
- v2.4.1(MySQL - 5.5.50)
- Jetty - v9.3.18(JDK 8+)
- OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Basically we are getting too many CLOSE_WAIT issue randomly. We’ve tried to figure out the solution and below are the list of references we’ve tried.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444031
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/High_Load

As suggested in above references we’ve updated /etc/sysctl.conf, /opt/jetty9/etc/jetty.xml and /etc/security/limits.conf files with below details:

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

> net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=20
>  net.core.rmem_max=16777216
>   net.core.wmem_max=16777216
>  net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=4096 87380
>   16777216
>  net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=4096 16384 16777216
>   net.core.somaxconn=4096
>  net.core.netdev_max_backlog=16384
>   net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192
>  net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
>   net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65535
>   net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
>  net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=cubic
>
> Then executes
>       Sysctl -p

**/opt/jetty9/etc/jetty.xml**

```
<!-- Server Thread Pool -->
    <Set name="ThreadPool">
      <!-- Default queued blocking threadpool -->
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">

        <Arg>
           <New class="java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue">
              <Arg type="int">6000</Arg>
           </New>
      </Arg>

        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
```

**/etc/security/limits.conf**

root    hard nofile    40000
root    soft nofile     40000

We’ve also gone through the code optimization steps, still no luck. I have gone through fundamental of TCP connection states, and cause of CLOSE_WAIT state then tried above ways as mentioned, also gone through many questions related to CLOSE_WAIT on stackoverflow and tried to resolve the issue as people mentioned solutions over there but didn’t get any success.

Can anyone face the same issue and found any solution?

Comment: I also facing this problem, trying to resolve since 2 months, actually this problem is well known but not identified any proper solution till date.